# sql design tables best way to make value groups?

Tags: sql, postgresql

My client can add his own attributes so I create a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE attr (
  id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  value VARCHAR
)
```

Now I want that he can group some values together maybe you have a location and you set 5 attr toegther that you dont click everytime when you choose a location the same attr. You can select the group then all 5 attr/values are in there. So how I design this ? Or whats the best way to do this? Here is right now my example:

```
CREATE TABLE attr_groups (
   id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
   name VARCHAR // he can say a group name like "Black clothes" or "White clothes",
)

CREATE TABLE attr (
  id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  group_id INT,
  value VARCHAR
) 

CREATE TABLE location (
   id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
   attr_group_id INT REFERENCES attr_groups(id),
   name VARCHAR,
   start TIMESTAMP,
   end TIMESTAMP
)
```

Whats you advise ? What I am doing wrong or is that the right way ? I hope you can give me some tips

Comment: What are the desired relationships? Can you have multiple `location` per `attr_group`, can a `location` exist without an `attr_group`? Or vice versa?

Comment: @Charlieface you can use 1 group per location and a location can exists without attr_group. attr group is only optional

Comment: Then your current setup looks correct.